# click event doesn't fire on ajax loaded objects

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm populating my cart using ajax. Within the cart I've got a quantity field with a plus and minus button.
This is the code for the buttons:

```
  <div class="cart-quantity">
                <input type='button' value='+' class='qtyplus CartCount' field='updates_{{ item.id }}' />
<input name="updates[]" id="updates_{{ item.id }}" class="quantity CartCount" value="{{ item.quantity }}" />
      <input type='button' value='-' class='qtyminus CartCount' field='updates_{{ item.id }}' />
  </div>
```

And here is the javascript to update the quantity field via the plus/minus button:

```
// This button will increment the value
$('.qtyplus').on("click", function(){
    // Stop acting like a button

    // Get the field name
    fieldName = $(this).attr('field');
    // Get its current value
    var currentVal = parseInt($('input[id='+fieldName+']').val());
    // If is not undefined
    if (!isNaN(currentVal)) {
        // Increment
        $('input[id='+fieldName+']').val(currentVal + 1);
    } else {
        // Otherwise put a 0 there
        $('input[id='+fieldName+']').val(0);
    }
    e.preventDefault();
$(this).closest('form').submit();
});
// This button will decrement the value till 0
$(".qtyminus").on("click",function() {
    // Stop acting like a button

    // Get the field name
    fieldName = $(this).attr('field');
    // Get its current value
    var currentVal = parseInt($('input[id='+fieldName+']').val());
    // If it isn't undefined or its greater than 0
    if (!isNaN(currentVal) && currentVal > 0) {
        // Decrement one
        $('input[id='+fieldName+']').val(currentVal - 1);
    } else {
        // Otherwise put a 0 there
        $('input[id='+fieldName+']').val(0);
    }
    e.preventDefault();
$(this).closest('form').submit();
});
```

As you can see I've tried changing the click event to on click but it's still not working. Any ideas?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Instead of binding the `click` event to the `.qtyplus` directly, try with:

```
$(document).on('click', '.qtyplus', function() { /* ... */ });
```

For the better performance, instead of binding it to `document`, use the closest `.qtyplus` elements parent.

Comment: Yes, dynamically loaded objects won't respond to events unless you bind to the $(document), or some other parent that is loaded before the listener was registered.

Comment: Literally just came across this in another post, thanks anyway!